# Android build fails after updating Vuforia to 10.18.4

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I updated Vuforia to 10.18.4 in a Unity project and now Android builds are failing. Builds have been fine for a year with a previous version of Vuforia (10.15.4).

Unity version 2021.3.29
Android min API level: 29
Android target API level: 33

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:dexBuilderDebug'.
> Key C:\Users\Work\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1a410a46e198714bef252bef3937ed12\jetified-VuforiaEngine-runtime.jar is missing in the map.
```

A development build will finish, a release build will not.

I've tried:

- Resolving dependencies using Googles 'External Dependency Resolver'
- Adding some Multidex stuff into Launcher Gradle template
- Deleting everything from inside .gradle\caches
- Other stuff I've forgotten

Answer (score 2):

Closing Unity, deleting the Library folder and relaunching stopped the error from happening.